# System.InvalidOperationException: 'RegisterSessionNotification has to be called from an MTA-Thread.'

Tags: c#, wpf, audio, cscore

So, I am trying to create a visualizer for the peak volume and I found this piece of code in the website which uses CsCore. So when I tried running it, it threw the following error message:

> **System.InvalidOperationException:** 'RegisterSessionNotification has to be called from an MTA-Thread.'

This is the piece of code I am working with

```
public static void getVolume() {
        using(var sessionManager = GetDefaultAudioSessionManager2(DataFlow.Render))
        {
            using(var sessionEnumerator = sessionManager.GetSessionEnumerator())
            {
                foreach(var session in sessionEnumerator)
                {
                    using(var audioMeterInformation = session.QueryInterface<AudioMeterInformation>())
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(audioMeterInformation.GetPeakValue());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static AudioSessionManager2 GetDefaultAudioSessionManager2(DataFlow dataFlow)
    {
        using(var enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator())
        {
            using (var device = enumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(dataFlow, Role.Multimedia))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("DefaultDevice: " + device.FriendlyName);
                var sessionManager = AudioSessionManager2.FromMMDevice(device);
                return sessionManager;

            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you are the victim of [somebody's library](https://github.com/filoe/cscore/blob/master/CSCore/CoreAudioAPI/AudioSessionManager2.cs#L151).  Why this is necessary is quite hard to guess, it is telling you that you need to do this in a worker thread.  Talk to the author or file a github issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On msdn, you can see the following remark:

> Note  Make sure that the application initializes COM with
>   Multithreaded Apartment (MTA) model by calling CoInitializeEx(NULL,
>   COINIT_MULTITHREADED) in a non-UI thread. If MTA is not initialized,
>   the application does not receive session notifications from the
>   session manager. Threads that run the user interface of an application
>   should be initialized apartment threading model.

Tests showed that you have to call this function from an mta thread.
Just execute the method through a new thread, a threadpool, a task, etc.
Just anything than the main ui thread.
These are some limitations of the windows core audio api's.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
Task.Run(() => yourRutine());
```

Comment: Hi Aleixbo, can you please elaborate on your response a bit? Please describe why it works so future users searching for the same answer understand both the concept and the fix.

Comment: You have to call your routine like this:
Task.Run(() => getVolume());
The reason as the error indicates (Multithreaded Apartment (MTA) model by calling CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED) in a non-UI thread) is that it **only works** with Threads o Task.
getVolume(); //failure
Task.Run(() => getVolume()); //run
Just execute the method through a new thread, a threadpool, a task.